# How to crop multiple images in a folder to a circular shape using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a folder of images and I want to crop them in a circular shape.

This is the original image:

[image: original image]

The result that I want is this:

[image: desired result]

My code is:

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import numpy as np

def mask_circle_solid(pil_img, background_color, blur_radius, offset=0):
    background = Image.new(pil_img.mode, pil_img.size, background_color)

    offset = blur_radius * 2 + offset
    mask = Image.new("L", pil_img.size, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.ellipse((offset, offset, pil_img.size[0] - offset, pil_img.size[1] - offset),         fill=255)
    mask = mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(blur_radius))

    return Image.composite(pil_img, background, mask)

def mask_circle_transparent(pil_img, blur_radius, offset=0):
    offset = blur_radius * 2 + offset
    mask = Image.new("L", pil_img.size, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.ellipse((offset, offset, pil_img.size[0] - offset, pil_img.size[1] - offset), fill=255)
    mask = mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(blur_radius))

    result = pil_img.copy()
    result.putalpha(mask)

    return result

def crop_max_square(pil_img):
    return crop_center(pil_img, min(pil_img.size), min(pil_img.size))

def crop_center(pil_img, crop_width, crop_height):
    img_width, img_height = pil_img.size
    return pil_img.crop(((img_width - crop_width) // 2,
                     (img_height - crop_height) // 2,
                     (img_width + crop_width) // 2,
                     (img_height + crop_height) // 2))


im = []

for f in glob.iglob("./*.jpg"):
    im.append(np.asarray(Image.open(f)))
thumb_width = 150

im = np.array(im)

list_files = os.listdir(".")
list_files.sort()
list_files.remove("Test.py")
list_files.remove(".DS_Store")

for i in range(0,len(im)):
    im_square[i] = crop_max_square(im[i]).resize((thumb_width, thumb_width), Image.LANCZOS)
    im_thumb[i] = mask_circle_transparent(im_square[i], 4)
    im_thumb[i].save(list_files[i])
```

I have used the functions from this article:

[Generate square or circular thumbnail images with Python, Pillow](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-square-circle-thumbnail/)

But I get this error:

```
line 30, in crop_max_square
    return crop_center(pil_img, min(pil_img.size), min(pil_img.size))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Is your question (mainly) about how to process multiple images in a folder or how to circularly crop one of them? They are two different things. If it's the latter please simplify your code and provide a [mre].

Comment: Actually how to process multiple imahes in the folder is my question. The code is running for a single image but my problem is how to iterate it over all the images in the folder. The cropped image has been cropped by using these funcrions, but I don't know how to do this process for all the images in the folder

Comment: OK, that additional information should be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really need to use numpy to load the files, but you can do what the "Sample code for batch processing" [of the page you shared](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-square-circle-thumbnail/) does:

```
import os
import glob
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter


def mask_circle_solid(pil_img, background_color, blur_radius, offset=0):
    background = Image.new(pil_img.mode, pil_img.size, background_color)

    offset = blur_radius * 2 + offset
    mask = Image.new("L", pil_img.size, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.ellipse((offset, offset, pil_img.size[0] - offset, pil_img.size[1] - offset), fill=255)
    mask = mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(blur_radius))

    return Image.composite(pil_img, background, mask)


def mask_circle_transparent(pil_img, blur_radius, offset=0):
    offset = blur_radius * 2 + offset
    mask = Image.new("L", pil_img.size, 0)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    draw.ellipse((offset, offset, pil_img.size[0] - offset, pil_img.size[1] - offset), fill=255)
    mask = mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(blur_radius))

    result = pil_img.copy()
    result.putalpha(mask)

    return result


def crop_max_square(pil_img):
    return crop_center(pil_img, min(pil_img.size), min(pil_img.size))


def crop_center(pil_img, crop_width, crop_height):
    img_width, img_height = pil_img.size
    return pil_img.crop(((img_width - crop_width) // 2,
                         (img_height - crop_height) // 2,
                         (img_width + crop_width) // 2,
                         (img_height + crop_height) // 2))


im = []
jpgs_files_path = "./" # Replace the "./" path by the path where the .jpg images are.
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(jpgs_files_path, '*.jpg')) 
thumb_width = 150

for f in files:
    im = Image.open(f)
    im_thumb = crop_max_square(im).resize((thumb_width, thumb_width), Image.LANCZOS)
    im_thumb = mask_circle_transparent(im_thumb, 4)
    ftitle, fext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))
    im_thumb.save(os.path.join("./dstdir/", ftitle + '_thumbnail.png'), quality=95)
```

As JPG does not support transparency you need to discard the Alpha Channel or save as something that supports transparency like PNG.